# Proper cleanup of the transition event listeners with option “once”

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm setting up a modal with a transition and want to listen to both start and end of the transition, so I set up both listeners when toggling on/off.

`transitionEl.addEventListener("transitionstart", () => { /* ... */}, { once: true });`

`transitionEl.addEventListener("transitionend”, () => { /* ... */}, { once: true });`

In this scenario, does using `once` option in the method's options object prevent proper cleanup if the element is removed during the transition and added back again (the first event would fire along with the second transition since it'd still be there in a new call)?

Comment: This is taken from the MDN page, describing the `once` option: **A boolean value indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If `true`, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked. If not specified, defaults to `false`.** So, by saying `{once: true}`, you're removing that. Each time it runs, it removes itself.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What I am describing here though will result in transitionEnd not being invoked in the case when the component is removed mid-transition.